# Property of modulo congruation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, modules, congruences

If I have:
$$a^b \equiv 1 \mod xy$$
where $x,y$ are primes,
is then true that:
$$ a^b \equiv 1 \mod x$$
$$ a^b \equiv 1 \mod y$$

I don't sure if this is true, because I don't know how can I prove it

Comment: From the definition of congruence to write $xy \mid a^b - 1$. Then you get $x \mid a^b - 1$ and $y \mid a^b - 1$.

Comment: Right! Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

$x = 1 \pmod {y(z+1)} \implies x = 1 \pmod {z+1}, \ = 1 \pmod y$.  Similarly, $ x = 1 \pmod {y(z+k)} \implies x = 1 \pmod{y}, \pmod{z+k}$.  Simlarly for any polynomial in $\Bbb{Z}[x_1, \dots, x_k], \ \ p(\bar{x}) = \ p_1(\bar{x}) \cdots p_n(\bar{x}), $ we have that if $z = z' \pmod {p(\bar{y})}$, then $z = z' \pmod{p_i(\bar{y})}, \ \forall i=1\dots n$.